# Installing ADO.Net hot fix installshield 2010

Tags: installshield-2010

How I can install ADO.net hot fix along with setup program which is developed in installshield 2010

please guide me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue.

I have created separate .prq(prerequisites) file and I use that .prq file with in my setup installation program.